# Infinite sequence

Tags: calculus

One of the major distinctions between a set and a sequence is that the order of terms matters in a sequence. Looking at a set of integers, am I right to say that we cannot have a sequence whose terms are all the integers?

I mean that $\{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,...\}$ is not a sequence because every sequence, finite or infinite, must have the first term. Since a sequence can be thought of as a function whose domain is a set of positive integers? Is that so?

Comment: We can have a sequence like $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,...$

Comment: There is no order preserving sequence of the integers, but there definitely are sequences. The simplest example of a sequence is $$f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb Z\\n\mapsto(-1)^n\cdot\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor$$where $n$ is the position in the sequence.

Comment: @BAI I agree with you but my question is if there is no first term, am I right to say that that is not a sequence?

Comment: Yes a sequence is a function from $\mathbb N$ to whatever set you want the sequence to be in. Another difference between it and a set is that repetition of elements is allowed in a sequence whilst it is meaningless in a set

Comment: @mamotebang yes. Otherwise it is not well-defined: for a function $f$ from the natural numbers, $f(1)$ is the first term

Comment: @mamotebang That would be correct. A sequence is a map from the positive integers to a set.

Comment: @BAI What do you mean by not well defined? It's just not a sequence.

Comment: @DonThousand Yes that what I meant

Comment: @BAI Well-defined has a precise meaning in mathematics. This is not the appropriate usage. But as long as we are clear as to what we mean.

Comment: You statement that $\{.....-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,....\}$ is not a sequence is correct.  But you question was "am I right to say that we cannot have a sequence whose terms are all the integers?"  And the answer to that is a resounding "No".  The statement "we cannot have a sequence whose terms are all the integers"  is very very very false.

Comment: "Since a sequence can be thought of as a function whose domain is a set of positive integers?"  Yes, but a function with the domain of positive integers and a range of all the integers (positive, negative, and zero) is quite possible and very common.  To conclude that they can't because the domain has a first element and the range does not is just plain wrong.

Comment: @fleablood,  I do agree with you and I admit that I did not ask my question precisely/ correctly. Anyway I was answered, I got what I needed to know.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to answer your question. First, the short answer:

The integers can be made into a sequence simply by choosing *any* first element. For example, @BAI's comment puts the integers in their standard order $0, 1, -1, 2, -2, \ldots$.

A slightly longer answer: Any countably infinite set $A$ may be made into a sequence by induction (or by reference to the bijection with $\Bbb{N}$ that witnesses the countability of the set). One simply chooses a first element $a_1$, then a second element $a_2 \neq a_1$, and so on.

Maybe more interestingly, there are so-called "bi-infinite" sequences, as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence). Such things *don't* have a first element, and the integers in their natural order form a bi-infinite sequence.

Comment: You don't need AC to put a countably infinite set into a sequence. They can be placed into a sequence by definition, since being countably infinite means being able to be placed in bijection with $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Yes! I'm used to creating sequences by pulling elements out of sets only known to be infinite. Will edit.

Comment: +1 In topology there is in fact a generalization of sequences called [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). Roughly, you can think of them as sequences with tree-like behavior. Whereas you previously had just a line with a fixed start point, you can now have an infinitely high and wide tree. (Just for OP's information :))

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at a set of integers, am I right to say that we cannot have a sequence whose terms are all the integers?

No, that is absolutely wrong.

> I mean that {...,−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3,4,...} is not a sequence because every sequence, finite or infinite, must have the first term.

$\{...,−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3,4,...\}$ is not a sequence but $\{0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,..... \}$ is.  It very easy to list all the integers in such a way that you have a first element.

> Since a sequence can be thought of as a function whose domain is a set of positive integers? Is that so?

I think this might be the key to your misunderstanding. Yes, the *domain* is a set of positive integers arranged from smallest to larger one after another.  And the range is a set ordered by position one after another.  But they needn't be, and usually are *not*, ordered by size.  They only need to be ordered by position.

The first can be anyone you want, the second any other, and you can certainly go through them all even though there is never a *smallest* one to start with.  You don't *need* to start with the smallest term in the *range*.  You need to start with the *first* term  in the range which could be any size.

It's very possible to have a $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$.  It's even possible for the function to be onto.

It is true $a < b$ will *not* mean that $f(a) < f(b)$ but there utterly no reason to think it should.  And yes it is true that if $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ is onto it will be impossible for $a<b$ to mean $f(a) < f(b)$.  But that is by no means a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up e.g. the sequence $\langle 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, \dotsc \rangle$. There are many others (like 0, then five positive numbers, then ten negative, then next five positive, ...).

More deeply: there are sets that can be placed in one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \dotsc\}$, they are called *countable*. As above, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ are a countable set. More interestingly, the set of pairs of integers is also countable (think of the pairs $(i, j)$ laid out in an infinite array, and walk along diagonals: $(1, 1)$, then pairs adding up to 3 $(1, 2), (2, 1)$, then pairs adding to 4, $(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)$, and so on). This means that the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is also countable! But it turns out that the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, is not countable (one would say it is "larger" in some sense, even if all are infinite).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to call what.

If you define a sequence to be a map defined on a well-ordered subset of the integers (that is, so that a sequence would always have a "first" member), then fine.

But in some other problems, it may be convenient for you to consider a sequence as being a map on any subset of the integers.

Answer (score 0):

The integers is a countable set, so you can enumerate the terms within the integers as a sequence. The sequence is as follows
0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3...... and so on.